# Why existing indexes slow down queries that don't use that index?

Tags: mongodb

By chance I found the following behavior:
In a collection with approximately 14000 documents with just two fields (_id and d), I do a heavy query, which happens to not take long just because I have few documents.

With no indexes, but the _id by default, the query with explain:

```
db.col.explain('executionStats').find({$or: [{_id: /^.*\bACCIDENT$/}, {d: /^.*\bACCIDENT.*$/}]}).limit(15)
```

throws the result (the relevant sections):

```
"winningPlan" : {
            "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
            "inputStage" : {
                "stage" : "LIMIT",
                "limitAmount" : 0,
                "inputStage" : {
                    "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
                    "filter" : {
                        "$or" : [
                            {
                                "_id" : /^.*\bACCIDENT$/
                            },
                            {
                                "d" : /^.*\bACCIDENT.*$/
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "direction" : "forward"
                }
            }
        },
        "rejectedPlans" : [ ]
"nReturned" : 15,
"executionTimeMillis" : 26,
"totalKeysExamined" : 0,
"totalDocsExamined" : 9834,
```

Then I create an index with

> db.col.createIndex({_id: 1, d: 1})

And then run the same query with explain (again just relevant sections):

```
"winningPlan" : {
    "stage" : "SUBPLAN",
    "inputStage" : {
        "stage" : "LIMIT",
        "limitAmount" : 0,
        "inputStage" : {
            "stage" : "COLLSCAN",
            "filter" : {
                "$or" : [
                    {
                        "_id" : /^.*\bACCIDENT$/
                    },
                    {
                        "d" : /^.*\bACCIDENT.*$/
                    }
                ]
            },
            "direction" : "forward"
        }
    }
},
"rejectedPlans" : [ ]

"nReturned" : 15,
"executionTimeMillis" : 57,
"totalKeysExamined" : 0,
"totalDocsExamined" : 9834,
```

As you can see, the winning plan is again a COLLSCAN, but this time it took twice as long.

So, I'm curious about what made mongodb take the extra time.

I'm using mongod 3.0.5.
The queries were executed from the mongo shell and made other examples with similar results, including the same query over and over again.

Comment: how often did you run this? could this be caused by something unrelated?

Comment: Unfortunately you have cut the output that actually **does** show the relevant information even if you have deemed it to not be so. In short, any "rejected plans" mean an attempt to see if the alternate approach "fits". This is not "free" and it takes time. Also the real problem here is that even though you use an "anchor" on the regex, the rest of the pattern cannot be resolved in an index in an optimal way. If you want a straight out comparison then use [`.hint()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) with both the defined index and the primary key repectively.

Comment: And make sure you warm the data on each attempt. A single query exection on each option is not a real comparison as index information and data need to be loaded. Several repeated attempts at each query will give you a "mean" response time that is realistic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Thilo.
My db has only this collection.
As I stated, I did many queries in both scenarios; and the execution time was pretty consistent.
Never in any case an index was used, in both scenarios a tablescan was executed.

Comment: Thank you @BlakesSeven for your attention.
My db has only this collection.
The rejected plans are actually what I got, that is empty square brackets. I suspected it had something to do with internals related to warming. But, as I stated, I did many queries in both scenarios.
Never in any case an index was used, in both scenarios a tablescan was executed.